# Macros that loop and transform a sequence of forms

Tags: hy

I am writing macros to simplify making plots with matplotlib. My first attempt, as follows, works correctly:

```
(defmacro insert-ax [body] `((getattr g!ax (str '~(first body))) ~@(rest body)))

(defmacro/g! plot [main &optional title [fig-kwargs {}]]
 `(do
   (import [matplotlib.pyplot :as plt] [time [ctime]])
   (setv [g!fig g!ax] (plt.subplots #**~fig-kwargs))
   (insert-ax ~main)
   (when ~title  (.set-title g!ax ~title))
   (.savefig g!fig (if ~title ~title (ctime)))))
```

Then the following code works as expected:

```
 (plot (scatter xs ys) "Data"))
```

which (in idiomatic Python) is equivalent to

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(xs,ys)
ax.set_title("Data")
fig.savefig("Data")
```

This is great, but I'd like to be able to pass multiple forms, each to be transformed with `insert-ax` so I can add multiple plots to `ax`, pass other options, etc. To be specific, this would be `do-plot` such that

```
(do-plot ((scatter xs ys) (scatter ys xs) "Data 2"))
```

is equivalent to (again in idiomatic Python)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(xs,ys)
ax.scatter(ys,xs)
ax.set_title("Data 2")
fig.savefig("Data 2")
```

But the following naïve attempts do not work:

```
(defmacro/g! do-plot [main &optional title [fig-kwargs {}]]
 `(do
   (import [matplotlib.pyplot :as plt] [time [ctime]])
   (setv [g!fig g!ax] (plt.subplots #**~fig-kwargs))
   (do (lfor cmd ~main (insert-ax cmd)))
   (when ~title  (.set-title g!ax ~title))
   (.savefig g!fig (if ~title ~title (ctime)))))
```

This returns a `NameError: name 'scatter' is not definedNameError: name 'scatter' is not defined`. But this is understandable: I'm unquoting `main` too soon, before it is processed by `insert-ax`. So the next natural attempt:

Now the error I get is `expanding macro do-plot NameError: name 'cmd' is not defined`. Which is probably due to the fact that `main` is not unquoted in order for the lfor loop/list comprehension to work. So the next step is to try to unquote the entire loop:

```
(defmacro/g! do-plot [main &optional title [fig-kwargs {}]]
 `(do
   (import [matplotlib.pyplot :as plt] [time [ctime]])
   (setv [g!fig g!ax] (plt.subplots #**~fig-kwargs))
   (do ~(lfor cmd main (insert-ax cmd)))
   (when ~title  (.set-title g!ax ~title))
   (.savefig g!fig (if ~title ~title (ctime)))))
```

Then my next error is `expanding macro do-plot AttributeError: 'HySymbol' object has no attribute 'c'`. Which seems to indicate (because AttributeError seems to relate to `getattr`) that `~(first body))` in the definition of `insert-ax` is being evaluated to `c`.

Finally, out of a cargo-cult behavior I tried the following

```
(defmacro/g! do-plot [main &optional title [fig-kwargs {}]]
 `(do
   (import [matplotlib.pyplot :as plt] [time [ctime]])
   (setv [g!fig g!ax] (plt.subplots #**~fig-kwargs))
   (do ~@(lfor cmd main (insert-ax cmd)))
   (when ~title  (.set-title g!ax ~title))
   (.savefig g!fig (if ~title ~title (ctime)))))
```

(despite thinking that unquote-splicing would fuse my forms). This fails silently and produces no output. Here however hy2py returns the same error `expanding macro do-plot AttributeError: 'HySymbol' object has no attribute 'c'`

What else can I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subroutines of macros are usually better written as functions than macros. Functions are more flexible to use (they're first-class objects), pose less potential for confusion, and are easier to test. Here's how I'd do this with `insert-ax` as a function:

```
(eval-and-compile (defn insert-ax [body]
  `((. g!ax ~(first body)) ~@(rest body))))

(defmacro/g! do-plot [main &optional title [fig-kwargs {}]]
 `(do
   (import [matplotlib.pyplot :as plt] [time [ctime]])
   (setv [g!fig g!ax] (plt.subplots #**~fig-kwargs))
   ~@(map insert-ax main)
   (when ~title  (.set-title g!ax ~title))
   (.savefig g!fig (if ~title ~title (ctime)))))
```

Notice that `eval-and-compile` (or `eval-when-compile`) is necessary to ensure the function is available during compile-time, when `(do-plot …)` is expanded. I also simplified `insert-ax` a bit internally, although this isn't necessary.

Also, you misplaced a paren in your call to `do-plot`. What you want is:

```
(do-plot ((scatter xs ys) (scatter ys xs)) "Data 2")
```

For completeness, to write `do-plot` using the original `insert-ax` macro, replace the above `~@(map insert-ax main)` with `` ~@(lfor cmd main `(insert-ax ~cmd)) ``.